# Rails 7 - Storing hash as additional fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails hash for ice_cube that is stored in a field called recurring that looks like this:

```
{:validations=>{:day=>[1, 2, 4]}, :rule_type=>"IceCube::WeeklyRule", :interval=>1, :week_start=>0}
```

I want to keep that but also store the day key in a field called `days` and the rule_type in a separate `rule_type` field. So I would have a DB column called `days` that would have `1,2,4` in it and a column called `rule_type` that would have "`WeeklyRule`" in it.

How do you reference the hash values on create of the model record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the hash values then save fields:

```
recurring = {:validations=>{:day=>[1, 2, 4]}, :rule_type=>"IceCube::WeeklyRule", :interval=>1, :week_start=>0}

days = recurring[:validations][:day]
=> [1, 2, 4] 
rule_type = recurring[:rule_type] # or recurring[:rule_type].gsub('IceCube::', '') if you want only WeeklyRule
=> "IceCube::WeeklyRule"
```